# jQuery hiding all visible elements before showing new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

So I have the following code:

```
function toggleTarget($element, cb) {
    $('.panel').each(function() {
       if($(this) != $element) {
           $(this).fadeOut('slow');
       }
    });
    $element.fadeToggle('slow', cb);
}
```

So basically you can `click` on multiple buttons that will show different `panels` so what I am trying to do is loop over all the possible `panels` and if any are shown hide them and then show the `panel` that relates to the button that was `clicked`

P.S very new to JS so please be patient and give full answers.

Comment: Add complete code, HTML also. _jsfiddle_ will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `fadeToggle` of `$element` a call back function of `$('.panel')`'s `fadeOut` function.

```
function toggleTarget($element, cb) {
    $.when(
        $('.panel').not($element).fadeOut('slow');
    ).done(function() {
        $element.fadeToggle('slow', cb);
    });
}
```

Comment: Now it just appears to flash on and off.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a demo. You can try this way,

***HTML :***

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

***jQuery :***

```
$("#container div").on("click", function(){
    var selectedDiv = $(this);
    $(this).parent().children("div").fadeOut();
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/mc20tba2/)